# Changing user's password (bcrypt) using PUT method (mysql2, sequelize, express)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, put, bcrypt

I'm trying to create a feature where a user can change their details. Other items work except when I try to allow the user to change their password.

**Edit:** The code works if I also change the password, if not it will crash the server and give the bcrypt error. Is there a way if I don't want to change the password? or do I have to separate them?

this is the error that I get:

```
Error: data and salt arguments required
```

routes

```
router.put('/:user_id/edit', validateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.user_id;
    const { email, 
            password, 
            first_name, 
            last_name,
            role_id } = req.body;

        await bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
            Users.update({
                email: email,
                password: hash,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                role_id: role_id
            }, { where: {user_id: userId} });
            res.json('User updated successfully');
        })
})
```

Comment: are you sure 'password' is not undefined?

Comment: @griFlo lol, you're right. I didn't input a password change. My problem is actually how do I make this code work if the user doesn't want to change the password. (updated my post)

Answer (score 1):

I just made an if statement for it lol. Sorry guys.

```
router.put('/:user_id/edit', validateToken, (req, res) => {
    const userId = req.params.user_id;
    const { email, 
            password, 
            first_name, 
            last_name,
            role_id } = req.body;

        if (password != undefined) {
            bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) => {
                Users.update({
                    email: email,
                    password: hash,
                    first_name: first_name,
                    last_name: last_name,
                    role_id: role_id
                }, { where: {user_id: userId} });
                res.json('User updated successfully');
            })
        } else {
            Users.update({
                email: email,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                role_id: role_id
            }, { where: {user_id: userId} });
            res.json('User updated successfully');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you want to make an edit profile feature but the problem is it crashes when you don't change the password as well. The solution is simple.

### Solution

You can deal with this by validating the input which is something you need to be careful with. The simplest way you can do this is by using an if statement like so:

```
if (email == '' || password == '' || ... || role_id == '') { // Check if all the parameters are given
   return false; // Will terminate the callback function
}
```

Although this is probably overkill and you would like to handle it in a better way like ignoring the part where you change the password os ots empty like so:

```
if (password != '') {
  // Change the password here
}
```

Another solution would be to move the password change functionality to another endpoint (or modify the endpoint so that it will change the password when a condition is met) and deal with passwords and general profile information separately which feels like a better approach but I'm not sure.